# React onSubmit are not triggered with some Form.Check checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, onsubmit

I have written modal window with dynamic fields. Text input, date and radio boxes works fine, but when I`m trying to use checkbox inputs it falls.
handleSubmit does not work and not goes into method body
AnswerQuestion:

```
function AnswerQuestion(props) {
    const {questionStore} = useContext(Context);
    const dispatch = useNotification();
    const question = questionStore.getActiveAnswer();
    const show = props.show;
    const handleClose = props.handleClose;
    const handleUpdate = props.handleUpdate;

    const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(question.id && question.answerEntity.answerType === "CHECKBOX"
        ? Array(question.answerEntity.options.length).fill(false)
        : []
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        if(question.id && question.answerEntity.answerType === "CHECKBOX") {
            const newCheckedState = question.answerEntity.options.map((option) => question.answerEntity.answer.includes(option));
            setCheckedState(newCheckedState);
        }
    }, [])

    const setInitialValues = () => {
        if (question.id) {
            return {
                author: question.author.username,
                question: question.question,
                answerType: question.answerEntity.answerType,
                options: question.answerEntity.options,
                date: question.answerEntity.answerType === "DATE" && question.answerEntity.answer ? new Date(question.answerEntity.answer) : new Date(),
                answer: question.answerEntity.answer ? question.answerEntity.answer : "",
            };
        } else {
            return {
                author: "",
                question: "",
                answerType: "",
                options: "",
                date: new Date(),
                answer: "",
            };
        }
    };

    const schema = yup.object().shape({
        author: yup.string().required(),
        question: yup.string().required(),
        answer: yup.string(),
        answerCheckBox: yup.array(),
        date: yup.date(),
    });

    const submit = (values) => {
        questionStore
            .answerActiveQuestion(question.answerEntity.answerType, values.answer, values.date)
            .then(() => handleUpdate());
        handleClose();
        dispatch({
            type: "SUCCESS",
            message: "Your answer was saved.",
            title: "Success"
        })
    }

    return (
        <Formik
            enableReinitialize
            render={(props) => {
                return (
                    <AnswerQuestionForm
                        {...props}
                        show={show}
                        handleClose={handleClose}
                        checkedState={checkedState}
                    ></AnswerQuestionForm>
                );
            }}
            initialValues={setInitialValues()}
            validationSchema={schema}
            onSubmit={submit}
        >
        </Formik>
    )
}
```

And AnswerQuestionForm:

```
    function AnswerQuestionForm(props) {
    const {
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        handleSubmit,
        handleChange,
        handleClose,
        setFieldValue,
        setFieldTouched,
        show,
        checkedState,
    } = props;

    function insertAnswerModule() {
        switch (values.answerType) {
            case "DATE":
                return (
                    <Col sm={9}>
                        <DatePicker
                            name="date"
                            value={Date.parse(values.date)}
                            selected={values.date}
                            className="form-control"
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                setFieldValue('date', e);
                                setFieldTouched('date');
                            }}
                        />
                    </Col>
                )
            case "SINGLE_LINE_TEXT":
                return (
                    <Col sm={9}>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="text"
                            name="answer"
                            value={values.answer}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            isValid={touched.question && !errors.question}
                            isInvalid={!!errors.question}
                        />

                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                            {errors.question}
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                    </Col>
                )
            case "MULTILINE_TEXT":
                return (
                    <Col sm={9}>
                        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3}
                                      type="text"
                                      name="answer"
                                      value={values.answer}
                                      onChange={handleChange}
                                      isValid={touched.question && !errors.question}
                                      isInvalid={!!errors.question}
                        />

                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                            {errors.question}
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                    </Col>
                )
            case "CHECKBOX":
                return (
                    <Col sm={9}>
                        {values.options.map((option, id) => (
                            <Form.Check
                                id={id}
                                type="checkbox"
                                name="answerCheckBox"
                                label={option}
                                value={option}
                                defaultChecked={checkedState[id]}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </Col>
                )
            case "RADIO_BUTTON":
                return (
                    <Col sm={9}>
                        {values.options.map((option) => (
                            <Form.Check
                                type="radio"
                                name="answer"
                                label={option}
                                value={option}
                                checked={option === values.answer}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </Col>
                )
        }
    }

    return (
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} centered backdrop="static">
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Answer the question</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Form>
                    <Row className="me-3 md-3 justify-content-between">
                        <Form.Group as={Row}>
                            <Form.Label column sm={3}>
                                From user
                            </Form.Label>
                            <Col sm={9}>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    name="author"
                                    value={values.author}
                                    readOnly
                                    disabled
                                ></Form.Control>
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="me-3 mt-3 md-3 justify-content-between">
                        <Form.Group as={Row}>
                            <Form.Label column sm={3}>
                                Question
                            </Form.Label>
                            <Col sm={9}>
                                <Form.Control
                                    type="text"
                                    name="question"
                                    value={values.question}
                                    readOnly
                                    disabled
                                ></Form.Control>
                            </Col>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="me-3 mt-3 md-3 justify-content-between">
                        <Form.Group as={Row}>
                            <Form.Label column sm={3}></Form.Label>
                            {insertAnswerModule()}
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Row>
                </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    SAVE
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

I would be glad to know where is error and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
I passed answer as string[] if answerType is "CHECKBOX". It`s not allowed in HTML and i changed answer type to string and it begins to work.